# Dar un formato diferente al guardar en un DataFrame en un csv

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

Estoy trabajando con un DataFrame de Pandas y le paso una lista para luego imprimirlo en el formato especifico que lo necesito pero no logro hacerlo

```
import pandas as pd 
 
df = pd.DataFrame(res) 
 
df.to_csv('file1.csv')
```

Esto me entrega el siguiente resultado ...

```
,0,1,2,3,4 
0,11,14,24,39,43 
1,11,14,24,39,49 
2,11,14,24,39,52 
3,11,14,24,39,73 
4,11,14,24,39,74 
5,11,14,24,39,75
```

Pero yo necesitaria que que asi ...

```
1|11 14 24 39 43 
2|11 14 24 39 49 
3|11 14 24 39 52 
4|11 14 24 39 73 
5|11 14 24 39 74 
6|11 14 24 39 75
```

**1ro**. que no me devuelva la Cabezara de la columna
**2do.** que empiece de 1 la indexacion
**3ro.** que en vez de poner , (coma) como separador ponga un espacio

Alguna idea ? ya se me quemaron los papeles.!!

Comment: indicale eso a pandas `.to_csv("file1.csv", sep="\s", header=None)`

Comment: y antes de eso cambas el index,`df.index = [_ for _ in range(1, len(df)+1)]`

Comment: @Christian puedes usar el constructor list `list(range(1, len(df)+1))`

Comment: @DanteS. la list comprehesion es más rápida y se evita la llamda a una clase y todo lo que trae consigo

Comment: @DanteS. nop, olvídalo, ya lo probé :/

Comment: @Christian yo también lo probé y creo que ambos llegamos a la misma conclusión. El constructor list es más rapido. SUPONGO que tiene que ver con que el bucle en el constructor está implementado en c.

Comment: @Christian sep="\s" no me funciona. Cuando lo pongo el archivo se crea vacio.

Comment: Creo q es mucho pedir que el Primer Separador sea el Palo invertido no?

Comment: entonces puedes especificarlo como un espacio en blanco `sep=" "`. Y sip, creo que eso ya escapa del poder de pandas. Incluso para cualquier programa, por ejemplo excel, pues el separador indica, como su nombre lo dice, el caracter para separar datos y sería inconsiste que haya 2 tipos de separadores

Comment: Y puedo quitar u oculptar el campo Index ?

Comment: si quieres quitar el index, también se lo especifícias `.to_csv(index=None)`

Comment: Genial  muchas gracias